# Why do mobile broadband modems (aka mobile Internet sticks, connect cards, data cards) have built-in memory card readers?

Tags: mobile-broadband, cellular

I doubt that anyone will be saving ringtones, mp3s and photos, and archiving contacts, messages and schedules on it --- *So what is it for?*

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, they are usually used for storing the drivers for the card, so you don't end up in the bothersome situation of needing to go online to get the drivers for the thing you need to get online.

Comment: Ryan, the modem's onboard read-only flash ram stores its drivers.  I am asking about the _card reader_, and these modems don't come with memory cards ... so why do they have memory card readers?

Comment: Afraid I don't have an answer to that one. I've yet to run into a 3g card with an SD slot on it.